# Feedburner customization

Tags: css, feed

I want use the feeds of the my entry blog in my site http://www.e-connecting.com/index/index.html. When I trying this, using buzzboost, spoils the appearance of my site (see my site). How I will be able to fix this?

I trying overridden that feedburnerFeedBlock style but same I don't get.

```
<div id="services">
<ul>
<li>
        <div class="fl_left"><img src="images/demo/100x180.gif" alt="" /></div>
        <div class="fl_right">
              <h2>linux  |  cisco  |  vmware  |  off topics</h2>
           <p><script src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/LinuxCiscoVmwareOffTopics? format=sigpro" type="text/javascript" ></script><noscript><p>Subscribe to RSS headline  updates from: <a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/LinuxCiscoVmwareOffTopics"></a> <br/>Powered by FeedBurner</p> </noscript>.

       </div>
</li>
.
.
.

.feedburnerFeedBlock {
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
}

#services ul, #services p, #services h2, #services img{
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style:none;
}

#services li{
display:block;
float:left;
width:294px;
height:180px;
margin:0 9px 0 0;
padding:10px;
color:#666666;
background-color:#EFEFEF;
}

#services li:hover, #services li:hover h2{
color:#666666;
background-color:#E5E5E5;
}

#services li.last{
margin-right:0;
}

#services .fl_right{
display:block;
float:right;
width:185px;
padding:10px 0 0 0;
}

#services h2{
margin:0 0 5px 0;
padding:0 0 3px 0;
font-size:14px;
font-weight:bold;
color:#666666;
background-color:#EFEFEF;
border-bottom-color:#666666;
}

#services p{
margin:0;
padding:0;
line-height:1.6em;
}

#services p.readmore{
display:block;
width:100%;
margin:15px 0 0 0;
padding:0;
text-align:right;
line-height:normal;
}

#services p.readmore a{
padding:8px 15px;
font-weight:bold;
color:#FFFFFF;
background-color:#666666;
}
```